# How to change colors in the Eclipse Content Assist (Template Proposals) window

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I'm using Eclipse Neon. After changing theme to Dark it is hard to distinguish a selected item in Content Assist from the foreground.

[image: screenFromEclipse]

Is it possible to change that colors within Eclipse (General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts) or anywhere else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse dark theme content assist unreadable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36342208/2985643).

Comment: You are right it is a duplicate. An answer provided there solves my problem.