# Eclipse Content Assist/Template Proposal: Unable to change the background of the highlighted line (selected by keyboard arrow, not mouse pointer)

Tags: eclipse, stm32cubemx

Hi I'm currently using STM's CubeMX to do some programming of my STM32 in C/C++.
I have also downloaded from marketplace the darkest dark theme (I selected darkest gray).

I immediately noticed that when I enter ctrl+space for the content assist/template proposal, I am hardly able to see which line of the proposal is highlighted. Do see the below image to understand what I mean.

I would like to change the BACKGROUND of the highlighted line/proposal (not the TEXT colour of the highlighted line) but to no avail.

I have gone through a few other posts in the past similar to this, but it does not refer to my specific situation.

I also noticed that if I were to mouse over (but it is much more inefficient), a slightly more distinguishable background colour could be seen.

Could someone advice how I can resolve this please?

Thanks

Example: [Eclipse dark theme content assist unreadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342208/eclipse-dark-theme-content-assist-unreadable)
[How to change colors in the Eclipse Content Assist (Template Proposals) window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754663/how-to-change-colors-in-the-eclipse-content-assist-template-proposals-window)

[image: Highlighted line is almost indistinguishable]

Comment: IIRC that's an issue that has been fixed. Probably your Eclipse is not up to date. In general, use a light theme, as the human eye needs light to work best.

Comment: @howlger, could you advice what might be the name of the item to change? Like it is called foreground/background of content assist highlight or something? I have just installed this STM CubeMX just 3 weeks ago so I doubt it is outdated.

Comment: STM CubeMX might use an outdated Eclipse platform. In _Help > About STM CubeMX: Installation Details_ what version is shown for the _Eclipse Platform_? Is this on Windows? If yes, it might be [this](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#dark-selection-win32-highlighter) ([Eclipse bug 562043](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=562043)).

Answer (score 0):

A light theme does not play as nice with syntax highlighting, as does a dark theme. Most programmers prefer a dark theme, which works best for the eyes, when you have to look so many hours to the screen every day. At least it does so for me.
To adjust "Completion proposal foreground" and "Completion proposal background"
in STM32CubeIDE, got to "Preferences" > "C/C++" > "Editor". Here you will find the settins under "Appearance color options".
I used:
Background 29, 29, 29
Foreground 156, 220, 254